# Wiremock error: body doesn't match even though it is already the same

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, wiremock

I register this wiremock in my test

```
wireMock.register(post("/processes/secure/private/addevent?caseid=101000000001")
        .withRequestBody(equalToJson("{\"note\":\"New reporter added:Please Select Individual\",\"title\":\"Reporter Updated\"}",true,true))
        .willReturn(ok()));
```

But it shows an error, the stub is not matching even though it is already the same
[The stub error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOkR0.png)

Do you know what is the root cause?
I also try change equalToJson with equalTo and still not working.

Comment: You might have some more success specifying a specific URL path matcher (`urlMatching()`, for example). Potentially also using `urlPathEqualTo` and a `.withQueryParam()` -- the issue may come from matching the URL and not the body.